# How can I split a string but keep the delimiters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have searched online but it really doesnt make much sense.

I am trying to split a string and keep the delimiters too.

For example, I have this string:

```
var str = '45612+54721/121*124.2';
```

And, I would like to split it based on the operations & keep the operations.

So the output must look like this

> [45612], [+], [54721], [/], [121], [*], [124.2];

Answer (score 6):

If you use strings’ `split` with a regex, any captured groups become part of the resulting array.

```js
var str = '45612+54721/121*124.2';
var tokens = str.split(/([+/*])/);
console.log(tokens);
```